# Monkey patch cursor.execute() and close() or not?

Tags: python, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, monkeypatching

"Trying to unit test my code using *unittest.mock* python library".
 I have code which is running database queries very similar to this:

app.py:

```
from flask import g
import mysql.connector
@app.route('/')
def create_table():
    g.db=mysql.connector.connect("credentials")
    cursor = g.db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(id INT NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(40),email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL)')
    cursor.close()
      g.db.close()
```

I have mocked my g.db using the below method, but from here I am struggling with how to mock `cursor.execute()` and `cursor.close()`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 def testtable():
   with patch('app.mysql.connector') as mock_mysql_connector:
    create_table()
    print g.db
   #mock execute and close#
```

On printing  `g.db` I'm getting *Mock* name and id, which I believe that means g.db is mocked, but I have no clue how I should mock `execute()` and `close()`.

Do I have to do monkey patching?
If yes, please provide a hint how to monkey patch them?
If no, then what is another way to mock them?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Is it about test cases (pytest etc.?)

Comment: @ mstuebner  I am doing unit testing using unittest.mock library of python  and for the purpose of testing instead of hitting  database i want to mock my connection ,execute() and close()

Answer (score 1):

You could use [patch.multiple](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-multiple):

```
from mock import patch, DEFAULT

with patch.multiple('app', mysql=DEFAULT, g=DEFAULT) as dict:
    # Mocking
    connector = dict[̈́'mysql'].connector
    db = connector.connect.return_value
    cursor = db.cursor.return_value
    # Run function to test
    create_table()
    # Assertions
    assert dict['g'].db == db
    db.close.assert_called_once_with()
    cursor.close.assert_called_once_with()
    connector.connect.assert_called_once_with("credentials")
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent,I have some questions that why   'cursor' is set   to   return_value of 'db.cursor' and what 'return values' i need to set as you mentioned

Comment: Consider reading the [mock module quick guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide), the [mock class documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class) and this [introduction to mocking in python](http://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python) to understand how to use mocks.

Comment: i read the documentation and understood that why you are using  cursor = db.cursor.return_value but i am still confuse at where you have mentioned #set return_value.Can you please explain me it little bit?

Comment: Well you could set `cursor.execute.side_effect` if you want something to happen when `cursor.execute` is called for instance. But considering the code you want to test, I don't think it is necessary to set any return values, since you're not using the result of `cursor.execute`.

Comment: i think i got what you are saying.Lets say i have a query cursor.execute'(select 'name' from table)                                                    name=cursor.fetchone()[0]                                                                        return name.                                                                                           so in this case i need to return_value right?like this cursor.execute.return_value='name'

Comment: Something like this yes. If the code you want to test contains `return cursor.fetchtone()[0]`, you could prepare the return value with `cursor.fetchone.return_value = ["some value"]`.

Comment: Thanks Vincent for your help.